# python Django NoReverseMatch error to product_detail.html

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

my product.html works fine but when I click on the link to take me to product_detail.html, I keep getting NoReverseMatch error. I have kept everything you will need to help me out below. I appreciate it if anyone of you help me because am stuck in this error for 2 days.

My Django folder structure is as follows

[image: My Django folder structure]

src/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('main.urls')),
    url(r'contact/', include('contact.urls')),
    url(r'product/', include('product.urls')),
]
```

product/urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', product, name='product'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', ProductDetail.as_view(), name='product_detail'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

product/models.py

```
class Products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/uploaded/products')
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    product_description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

product/views.py

```
    def product(request):
        products = Products.objects.all().order_by("-id")
        page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    
        paginator = Paginator(products, 6)
        try:
            products = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            products = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        context = {
            'products': products
        }
        return render(request, 'products.html', context)
    
    class ProductDetail(generic.DetailView):
        model = Products
        template_name = 'products_detail.html'
```

product.html

```
{% for p in products %}
            <div class="mb-4 mb-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="block-service-1-card">
                    <a href="{% url 'product_detail' p.slug  %}" class="thumbnail-link d-block mb-4">
                        <img src="{{ p.product_image.url }}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid" style="height: 400px; width: 400px">
                    </a>
                    <h3 class="block-service-1-heading mb-3"><a href="{% url 'product_detail' p.slug  %}">
                    {{ p.product_title }}
                    </a></h3>
                    <div class="block-service-1-excerpt"><p>{{p.product_description|slice:":20" }}
                        <a href="{% url 'product_detail' p.slug  %}"
                           class="d-inline-flex align-items-center block-service-1-more"><span>Find out more</span>
                            <span
                                    class="icon-keyboard_arrow_right icon"></span></a></p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

products_details.html

```
 <div class="block-service-1-card">
                    <a  class="thumbnail-link d-block mb-4"><img src="{{ p.product_image.url }}" alt="Image"
                                                                         class="img-fluid"></a>
                    <h3 class="block-service-1-heading mb-3"><a href="{% url 'product_detail' p.slug  %}"> {{
                        p.product_title }}</a></h3>
                    <div class="block-service-1-excerpt"><p>{{p.product_description }}</p></div>
                    </div>
```

The error that am getting is

```
NoReverseMatch at /product/fadfa/
Reverse for 'product_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

Comment: add your models.py

Comment: @shreyashmishra I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `product_details.html` you don't have the same loop as in the `products.html` thus `p` is an unknown variable in this context.

The [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView) supplies `object` variable containing appropriate model item.

So try changing all the `p.***` in `product_details.html` to `object.***`, e.g.

```
<a href="{% url 'product_detail' object.slug  %}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

please use something like this in your
urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', product, name='product'),
    path('<slug:title>/', ProductDetail.as_view(), name='product_detail'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in your html
product.html

```
div class="mb-4 mb-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="block-service-1-card">
                    <a href="{% url 'product_detail' request.Products.title %}" class="thumbnail-link d-block mb-4">
                        <img src="{{ p.product_image.url }}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid" style="height: 400px; width: 400px">
                    </a>
                    <h3 class="block-service-1-heading mb-3"><a href="{% url 'product_detail' p.slug  %}">
                    {{ p.product_title }}
                    </a></h3>
```

the way you trying to create you ulrpattern are not the best ways acc to me
and also check your html file name because you mention product_detail.html in your views.py but you i think you named it product_details.html as you wrote here